# Help needed for mathematical formulation

Tags: notation

I'm trying to write a simple mathematical formulated which expresses the following:

Let F={f1,f2,...,fn} be an ordered set of flights, each  *f* being associated with  a begin time *begin(f)* and an end time *end(f)*. Moreover, each flight is assigned to some gate g \in G. A boolean variable x_{f,g} takes the value 1 if *f* is allocated to *g*, and 0 otherwise.

I would like to find a way to define the value p(f), which is the immediate previous flight of a flight  *f* at gate g \in G.  I was thinking to express p(f) as follows:

p(f) = {f' ∈ F : ∃g ∈ G, x_f,g = 1 and x_f' ,g = 1, max(end(f')) and end(f') ≤ begin(f)}

This means that p(f) is a set which can either be empty or have one value (flight ID).  However, it is more natural for me to represent p(f) as a single value and not a set, but I do not now how to formulate it in that case. I'm grateful for any comments.

Thanks,
 Una

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this is to assign a value that cannot be a flight number, say $-1$, when there is no predecessor and $p(f)$ would be empty.  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Ross, thank you for your reply. I was also thinking to assign -1 to a non-existing flight. However, I would like to know how to express the same statement as defined above, without defing p(f) as a set.

Comment: You could use the expression you have, just taking the braces off.  Then it will have an integer value.  You need a bit of a clause for the $-1$ case